# iOS Push Notification self signed certificate

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, apple-push-notifications, cordova-plugins

I made project using `Cordova` and I am trying to port it to other platforms. I already successfully build everything for android. But I have problem with building it for iOS (cordova build ios --release --device). My project include Firebase plugin which is used for push notifications. I am trying to sign this application with self-signed certificate (app will be used internally, no app store). But when I try to sign this application, I got an error as,

> provisioning profile requires push notification permission.

Is there any way to avoid apple developer account (and 100$ ann. fee) and use self-signed certificates?

I tried creating a manual provisioning profile, no success. I researched a lot, but this subject is not really covered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the answer is NO.

Firebase using APNs to send push notifications which is Apple service :)

Maybe you can create an app with some Message Queue to receive messages like notifications based on sockets and display local notifications. But still, you will need developer account if you want to distribute the app to more devices. I think it is better just to pay 100$.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, really appreciate that. I tried everything but it looks like that you must pay for that.

Comment: You still can mark some of the answers as correct ;)